# Sliding navigation drawer as Relative Layout, DONE PROGRAMMATICALLY

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, drawer

i'm having problems with navigation drawer.

I setted the drawer layout and everything but when it comes to the real "drawer pane" and i want to open it, i get an exception saying:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout{699e897 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-1440,2464} is not a sliding drawer

So here is the code:

```
drawerPane=new RelativeLayout(activity);   
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawerPane_params=new
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(280, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
drawerPane.setGravity(Gravity.START);

drawerPane.setLayoutParams(drawerPane_params);

drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)activity.getRootView();
//getRootView is a custom function, returns the contentview (see updates below)
drawerLayout.addView(drawerPane);
```

in this code, the drawerlayout is the RootView of my activity (named: "activity")

i have a button which opens my drawer on buttonclick, and the code is this:

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerPane);
```

The error gets shown here.

Any suggestions? Thanks

**UPDATE**

this is the code i use to set drawerlayout as rootView:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myGestureDetector=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        rootView=new DrawerLayout(this);
        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams lp=new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        getRootView().setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        setContentView(rootView,lp);
        init(); //i made this function

        ViewGroup container=(ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(myLayout,null);
//myLayout is evaluated in init(), a function i created to set the CONTAINER of the app, that is, the first child after the drawlayout.

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp2=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        container.setLayoutParams(lp2);

        container.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        rootView.addView(container);
```

Comment: can you show where you set the DrawerLayout as root for the Activity?

Comment: @Ryoghurt Done, hope it helps.

Comment: `drawerPane` needs to have `DrawerLayout.LayoutParams` set on it, and you need to set the `gravity` on those `LayoutParams`. Furthermore, you need to add the drawer to the `DrawerLayout`, not its root `View`.

Comment: @MikeM. i edited the post in order to let you see more code, hope it can help more now.

Comment: OK, you still need to set the `LayoutParams` correctly. That's part of the reason why it doesn't think `drawerPane` is a drawer.

Comment: @MikeM. What do you mean by saying "set Layoutparams correctly"? should I explicitly call setLayoutParams? EDIT: i  used "setlayoutparams" but nothing changed.

Comment: Well, I don't know what code you're running now, but it's as simple as this: the drawer `View` needs to have `DrawerLayout.LayoutParams` with the appropriate `gravity`, and it needs to be added to the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. so from what i mean the error is not here, and gravity is correctly set, doesn't it? maybe i'm getting errors retrieving the drawpane...gonna check this.